# AS3 MouseMove laggy issue with transparency on FireFox

Tags: actionscript-3, firefox, transparent

I'm using a Custom Cursor when hovering a movieclip by using MOUSE_MOVE

```
spectrum.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,function(e:MouseEvent):void{
            Mouse.hide();
            mouseCursor.visible = true;
            mouseCursor.startDrag(true);
            mouseCursor.mouseEnabled = false;
            mouseCursor.mouseChildren = false;
            e.updateAfterEvent();
});
```

when I set
 **wmode='transparent'**

MOUSE_MOVE still works smoothly on Chrome and IE, but on FireFox the cursor becomes super laggy when hovering the MovieClip..any ideas why?

I also tried EnterFRAME with the Custom Cursor, but it's also laggy..

If I set  **wmode ='window'** MOUSE_MOVE works again, and not laggy anymore..

**Why does  mousemove become so laggy when setting wmode='transparent' on FireFox** ? Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your problem is wmode = transparent!

Rather than constantly starting the drag, you should rather either just start it once and then stop it when you dont need it anymore

or

just set the cursors position rather than using drag.

```
    spectrum.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,function(e:MouseEvent):void{
        Mouse.hide();
        mouseCursor.visible = true;
        mouseCursor.mouseEnabled = false;
        mouseCursor.mouseChildren = false;
        mouseCursor.x = mouseX;
        mouseCursor.y = mouseY;
```

});

Comment: No, just tierd your code, still laggy as hell when wmode is transparent... but it works smoothly when wmode is window..